# How can I append message context to a json array? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a personal Discord bot I am working on with discord.py and am trying to append all message content after a command to a json array so that it can be read from later.

Ideally I would like to tell the bot `.add Message content to be added.` and have that appended to the array. My command looks like the following:

```
@client.command(
        name='add',
        pass_context=True
        )
async def add(ctx, *, content:str):
        with open("/path/to/file.json","a+") as f:
                json.dump(content, f)
        await client.say("Added!")
```

This overwrites the entire file with the message content. How can I simply append?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it.

```
@client.command(
        name='add',
        pass_context=True
        )
async def add(ctx, *, content:str):
        with open("/path/to/file.json","r") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
        data.append(content)
        with open("/path/to/file.json","w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
        await client.say("Added!")
```